# JPA session factory query returning Null list

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a spring boot rest api, in that case when i am using a custom query from repository it is returning a null list, and the worst thing is there in no exception on eclipse console.
**** Another Thing**********
I have another controller having different service and repository, that is working correctly.
**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Navigation_Master")
public class Navigation_Master {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Nav_ID")
    private int Nav_ID;
    
    @Column(name="Nav_TS_ID")
    private int Nav_TS_ID;
    @Column(name="Nav_Application_ID")
    private int Nav_Application_ID;
    @Column(name="Nav_Page_ID")
    private int Nav_Page_ID;
    @Column(name="Nav_Reg_ID")
    private int Nav_Reg_ID;
    @Column(name="Nav_UnloadEvent")
    private String Nav_UnloadEvent;
    @Column(name="Nav_RedirectEvent")
    private String Nav_RedirectEvent;
    @Column(name="Nav_AppCache")
    private String Nav_AppCache;
    @Column(name="Nav_TTFB")
    private String Nav_TTFB;
    @Column(name="Nav_Processing")
    private String Nav_Processing;
    @Column(name="Nav_DomInteractive")
    private String Nav_DomInteractive;
    @Column(name="Nav_DomComplete")
    private String Nav_DomComplete;
    @Column(name="Nav_ContentLoad")
    private String Nav_ContentLoad;
    @Column(name="Nav_PageLoad")
    private String Nav_PageLoad;
    @Column(name="Nav_EntrySyetemTimes")
    private Timestamp Nav_EntrySyetemTimes;
// Getter & setter $ constructors 
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/getNavs/{tcId}/{appid}/{pageId}/{uId}")
    public List<Navigation_Master> findPageByName(@PathVariable("appid") String appid, @PathVariable("pageId") String pageId, @PathVariable("tcId") String tcId,
                                                    @PathVariable("uId") String uId) {
        return navigation_MasterService.getTopOneNavigation(tcId, appid, pageId, uId);
    }
```

**Service:**

```
@Override
    public List<Navigation_Master> getTopOneNavigation(String appid, String pageId, String tcId, String uId) {
        System.out.println(appid+" " + pageId + " "+ tcId + uId);
        return navigation_MasterReposity.findNavByParam(Integer.parseInt(tcId), Integer.parseInt(appid), Integer.parseInt(pageId), Integer.parseInt(uId));
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface Navigation_MasterReposity extends JpaRepository<Navigation_Master, Integer> {

    @Query(value="select * from Navigation_Master p where p.Nav_TS_ID=:tcid and p.Nav_Application_ID=:apid and p.Nav_Page_ID=:pgid and p.Nav_Reg_ID=:uid order by p.Nav_ID desc", nativeQuery=true) 
    List<Navigation_Master> findNavByParam(@Param("tcid") int tcid,
                                        @Param("apid") int apid,
                                        @Param("pgid") int pgid,
                                        @Param("uid") int uid);
    
}
```

in case when i am running this i am getting an empty list. please help me solve the issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check from the logs if it is running the requested query and the binding parameters are correct? To see the sql and the binding parameters in the console/logs, you can add these 2 lines in application.properties/yaml: `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`

Comment: @jumping_monkey I checked and found that parameters are not getting values properly. Debugging solved the issue. Thanks a lot for quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check from the console/logs if the requested query is correct with the right values in the binding parameters.

To see the sql and the binding parameters, add these 2 lines in application.properties/yaml:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Cheers